# setFullscreen in a ComboBox

Tags: javafx, combobox, fullscreen

Hello I am programming a UI for a game. In this UI I want a Scene with settings. In the settings I have a `ComboBox` where I want `setFullscreen` in true or false. Actually I get the Error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method `setFullScreen(boolean)` from the type " how can I solve my Problem. I want that the BorderlessWindow  `setFullscreen` true the `println` are working.

CONTROLLER CLASS;

```
package Menue;

public class SettingEinstellungen {


    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> Combobox;                                                                  
    ObservableList <String> Auswahl = 
            FXCollections.observableArrayList("Fullscree","Windowmode","Borderless Window");        


    @FXML 
    Button exit;                                                                                               
    @FXML
    public void initialize() {                                                                              



        Combobox.setValue("Fullscree");
        Combobox.setItems(Auswahl);
        Combobox.getSelectionModel().select("Fullscreen");


        Combobox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>(){       
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String alt, String new) {

            if(new != null) {
                switch(new) {

                    case "Fullscreen":  System.out.println("Vollbildgeklickt" +alt +neu);
                            break;      
                    case "Window-mode":     System.out.println("Fenster\t" +alt);
                            break;
                    case "Borderless Window":   Stage.setFullScreen(true);          
                            break;   
                    default: ;
                            break;
                }
            }

            }

        });}

    //public void changeCombo(ActionEvent  event) {

        //Stage.setFullscreen(true)(comboBox.getValue(Vollbild));

    //}

    @FXML   
    public void exit_press (ActionEvent  event) throws IOException  {                                   

        Stage window = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        //window.setFullScreen(true);
        //window.setScene(new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(new File("menue_UI_1.fxml").toURI().toURL())));

        Parent root_3 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("menue_UI_2.fxml"));
        Scene scene_3 = new Scene(root_3);
        window.setScene(scene_3);

        window.setTitle("Hauptmenü");
        window.show();

    }


}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not referencing the actual stage which is why you are getting that error you need to reference the actual stage that is shown you can do this by getting the window during execution like so or you can initialize it at the top when you start the program

```
comboBox.getSelectionModel()
            .selectedItemProperty()
            .addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {

                if(newVal != null) {
                    System.out.println(newVal);
                    switch(newVal) {
                        case "Fullscreen":
                            System.out.println("Vollbildgeklickt" +oldVal + newVal);
                            break;
                        case "Window-mode":
                            System.out.println("Fenster\t" +newVal);
                            break;
                        case "Borderless Window":
                            Stage window = (Stage) comboBox.getScene().getWindow();
                            window.setFullScreen(true);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }

            });
```